# How to get path of JSON object in Jackson JsonMappingException

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using Jackson to deserialize JSON of this form:

```
{
  "foo" : { "bar" : "baz" } 
}
```

The jackson code might look like:

```
  @JsonCreator
  public class MyProxy {
      @JsonProperty("foo") final FooProxy foo;
  }

  public class FooProxy {
      @JsonProperty("bar") final String bar;
  }
```

Imagine a consumer of this API creates invalid JSON like this:

```
{
  "foo" : { "bar" : 1 }
}
```

However, in this case, I receive a `MismatchedInputException` and the error looks like this:

> Cannot construct instance of `MyProxy` (although at least one Creator
>   exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize
>   from Number value (1)

When I inspect the MismatchedInputException, and I call `ex.getPathReference()` I get:

> FooProxy["bar"]->java.lang.Object[0]

I would like to be able to return the path to the broken value to the user without any reference to the underlying Java classes.

```
"foo.bar must be an Object."
```

How can I return an error message with the JSON path, and remove any reference to the Java implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;


public class DeserializationErrorTest {

  @Test
  void testDeserializeWrongInput() throws IOException {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
      mapper.readValue("{\"foo\" : { \"bar\" : \"not-int\" }}", MyProxy.class);
    } catch (MismatchedInputException e) {
      throw remapMismatchedInputException(e, RuntimeException.class);
    }
  }

  private <T extends Exception> T remapMismatchedInputException(final MismatchedInputException e, Class<T> exClass) {
    try {
      final String fieldName =
          e.getPath().stream().map(JsonMappingException.Reference::getFieldName).collect(Collectors.joining("."));
      return exClass.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(fieldName + " must be of type " + e.getTargetType().getSimpleName());
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException pE) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot instantiate exception class " + exClass.getSimpleName());
    }
  }

  static class MyProxy {
    @JsonProperty("foo") final FooProxy foo;

    @JsonCreator
    public MyProxy(@JsonProperty("foo") final FooProxy pFoo) {foo = pFoo;}
  }

  static class FooProxy {
    @JsonProperty("bar") final Integer bar;

    @JsonCreator
    public FooProxy(@JsonProperty("bar") final Integer pBar) {bar = pBar;}
  }
}
```

And will result in:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: foo.bar must be of type Integer
```

Comment: e.getPath() returns a list of all hierarchies of the field with the error. In case of nested objects your method will return the same error for each element in the hierarchy